# Integration testing with Capybara

Tags: rspec, sinatra, capybara, integration-testing

I'm trying to do a integration test of my app to get covered all the funcionalities. My app just uploads a file and it leads you to another page with a message 'Your database has been updated¡¡'. The user can't see it but when he uploads the excel file it updates the database. Well, I've used Capybara with Rspec to be able to test that I upload an excel file. The test pass to green but I don't understand why, cause I've written a false message to check that the test works propperly and still passes... I'm newby so I need some help please

spec/app_integration_spec.rb

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'app.rb')
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
Capybara.app = LaMareta

describe "Updating Vip customers database", :type => :feature do
  before {
    DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://david:123456@localhost/usersmareta')
    DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
  }
  after {
    clients_database = VipClient.all
    clients_database.each { |client| client.destroy }
  }
  it "Uploads succesfully an excel file with Vip customers data birhtday" do
    visit '/'
    attach_file('birthdayFile', 'spec/fixtures/databasetest.xlsx')
    click_button 'Upload_excel'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Hola'
  end
end
```

upload.rb

```
<h1>My file uploader!!</h1>
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type='file' name='birthdayFile' accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel">
  <input type='submit' value='Upload!' id="Upload_excel">
</form>
```

uploaded_file.rb

```
<h1>Your database has been updated¡¡</h1>
```

Edit my question

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Comment: How are you running the test? What's the output?

Comment: I put rspec spec/app_integration_spec.rb and the output is Updating Vip customers database
WARN: tilt autoloading 'tilt/erb' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'tilt/erb' suggested.
  Uploads succesfully an excel file with Vip customers data birhtday

Finished in 1.07 seconds (files took 3.31 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures

Comment: And the string `Hola` appears nowhere in your code other than in the spec?

Comment: Yes, I've put Hola as the result in the spec waiting to test fails...but it doesn't, so it tells me that I'm doing something wrong. It might be the configuration, because I don't see anything wrong in the test

Comment: Add a call to `puts page.body` before the `expect` to see what's actually on the page.